# How can I add custom next/previous buttons to fsLightbox?

Tags: javascript, lightbox

I'm using a lightbox plugin called fsLightbox (https://fslightbox.com). I need to add custom next/previous buttons but I don't understand how. I don't see any information in the documentation. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Update:
This plugin has built-in next previous buttons that appear on either side of the lightbox. I want to add additional next/previous buttons within the lightbox with custom text (the name of the next or previous slide). To accomplish this I'm using a custom source:

```
<a data-fslightbox="partners" data-class="partner" href="#FirstPartner">
  <img src="FirstPartner.jpg" />
</a>
<a data-fslightbox="partners" data-class="partner" href="#SecondPartner">
  <img src="SecondPartner.jpg" />
</a>

<div class="display-none">
  <div id="FirstPartner">
    <div class="copy-container">
      Some copy
    </div>
    <div class="navigation-container">
      <button onclick="NextSlide()">
        Second Partner >>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="SecondPartner">
     <div class="copy-container">
      Some copy
    </div>
    <div class="navigation-container">
      <button onclick="PrevSlide()">
        << First Partner
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide us a little playground?

Comment: fslightbox is available in vanilla js, react and vue. What are you planning to use?

Comment: Vanilla js. Thank you

Comment: How custom do you want your buttons? Customized css or own images?

Comment: Just text... the name of the "partner" of the next slide. I was thinking the button text  would be hard coded and I'd call a "nextSlide()" function somehow.

Comment: Do you want to set your text dynamically? I've made a version where it is set as `My Text`

Answer (score 0):

Since the library does not seem to allow custom buttons there always exists is a css solution.

First we need to hide the `svg` arrows by setting `display: none`.

```
.fslightbox-slide-btn svg {
  display: none;
}
```

After that the `content` is being replaced by `My text`.

```
.fslightbox-slide-btn:after {
  content: 'My text';
  color: white;
}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

### Live Demo

[image: Edit vibrant-dawn-sjgr1c]

Comment: Unfortunately that's not going to work for me.  The "My Text" needs to reside inside each hidden <div> that populates the lightbox.

Comment: I believe this is a css only solution. You could try something related to inline style if it needs to be dynamically changed. In react it would probably be possible, I don't know about vanilla js though.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to bind the next/prev events from the fslightbox.js file to these new custom buttons?

Comment: I think you would need to inspect `fslightbox.js`. There must be some functions that fire that event.